# What Libreoffice function or method will copy the formatted text of a cell rather than the data

Tags: libreoffice-calc

A1 = "=now()"
Which when formatted looks like:
January

I want to copy that "January" into a string of text such as:
="The month is" & A1

How do I copy the text? The output I get now looks like:
The month is 43834.6915531366

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, was not the one I really wanted as it is not very transferable but it was simply:
="The month is"&TEXT(A1,"mmmm")